# Log Reader Agent Blocking Distributor Agent T-log Stuck with log_reuse_wait_desc Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transaction-log

I've got a nasty SQL Server 2012 replication issue. I have a transactional publication going to a pull subscriber. 
The log reader agent on the publisher has gotten stuck in a loop of:

> *Delivering replicated transactions, xcount: 1 with an increasing command count messages*

and

> *The replication agent has not logged a progress message in 10 minutes*

messages.

So the log reader agent seems to be working but nothing is being replicated to the distributors. All distributors state

> *The process is running and is waiting for a response*

or they ***timeout*** and try again.
When I run `sp_whoisactive`, I see the spid for the log reader agent for that database is blocking all the distribution agents from the subscribers of that database....yet the status of the log reader process is **sleeping**.  The t-log for the publication database is growing fast and eating up storage. It's stuck with `log_reuse_wait_desc=REPLICATION`, so I cannot shrink it. Anyone run into this before? Any suggestions on how to fix this? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Update: I've upped the query timeout for log reader agent to 42300 (12 hours) as suggested to me on twitter #sqlhelp. This helped, log reader now scanning Tlog continuosly. This is some progress but the scanning of the tlog is taking a very long time and still no data sent to the distro agents.! Hopefully once done it'll start sending data to the distro agents. I'm in wait & see mode now. I'm thinking my only resort will have to be a reinitialize. That is a truly last resort as our publication is huge.  Open to tips too.